# Bogotá–Medellín by bus

Tags: public-transport, buses, colombia, bogota, medellin

On the map, the distance between the two biggest cities of Colombia doesn't seem that long at first (245 km as the crow flies).

[image]
<sup>[Bing Maps](http://www.bing.com/)</sup>

Then again *driving distance* is around [418](https://goo.gl/maps/D5AwGdJG1JJ2)–[539](http://www.distancecalculator.net/from-bogota-to-medellin) km according to quick search. Anyway, I was wondering how good an option an intercity bus might be.

With **safety**, **quickness** and **price** being priorities (in that order):

- General experiences on this particular route? Does it make sense to take the bus (instead of flying)?
- Are there any bus companies to be preferred (or avoided)? (Are there similar high-quality operators as in many other South American countries?)
- What's the price and duration approximately, and how often there are connections?
- Is there a website that's good for schedules?

My guidebook (Moon) seems to generally recommend flying to get around Colombia, and doesn't give those details. It does mention that *Terminal del Norte* in Medellín and (apparently) *Terminal de Transportes* in Bogotá are the relevant stations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Results of quick online research:

- There seem to be good, comfy buses. At least [Bolivariano](http://www.bolivariano.com.co/) (see [Bogota-Medellin route info](http://www.bolivariano.com.co/rutas-y-destinos/bogot%C3%A1-medell%C3%ADn)). Based on their marketing (see e.g. [DuoBus video](http://www.bolivariano.com.co/buses/duobus)), it *seems* nice and safe (but I don’t know about the road and areas passed through etc).
- Plenty of departures. Bolivariano has ~13 daily ([6:40 AM to 10:47 PM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDX4J.png)) (for Wednesday)
- Cost is affordable, 65,000 to 80,000 COP (20–25 USD)
- Main drawback: duration **10 hours**

Point of comparison: a BOG-MDE flight from [VivaColombia](http://vivacolombia.co) (for tomorrow):

- 62,900–93,300 COP (19-28 USD)
- Flight time **1h 10min**

So, cost being about the same, even with the airport hassle (getting to/from + waiting; maybe 2-3 hours total?), 10 hours is *a lot*, maybe a bit too much.

---

Feel free to post better answers, especially if you have first hand experiences. (How about safety on the bus trip & at the terminals? If you take a night bus are they good for sleeping?)

Comment: Regarding VivaColombia: I can't find them in the IATA IOSA registry https://www.iata.org/whatwedo/safety/audit/iosa/Pages/registry.aspx?Query=VivaColombia but that's not unusual for low cost airlines, they now http://www.miamiherald.com/news/business/article47846225.html fly to the USA which is a big plus: they do not allow unsafe aircraft into US airports.

Comment: I did the trip by bus. It was more than fine. No hassles, if long.

Comment: @chx: Yep, I wouldn't have hesitations about [VivaColombia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VivaColombia), which a traveller friend recommended to me. It's quite mainstream now, uses Airbus A320 fleet, and has had no major accidents.

Comment: Well, I ended up flying, with Avianca, easy and fast.